# How to install ProtonMail on Ubuntu Server 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, apt, dpkg

I have a PRO account at ProtonMail and I want to use it for my web server. I found a tutorial here :

https://pychao.com/2018/10/13/use-protonmail-bridge-on-headless-linux-machines/#comment-6612

https://pychao.com/2018/10/14/use-protonmail-for-wordpress-servers-smtp-setting-on-google-cloud-platform/

On my server, I tried the following command line :

```
$ sudo apt install pass
$ wget -c https://protonmail.com/download/protonmail-bridge_1.2.7-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i protonmail-bridge_1.2.7-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install protonmail-bridge
```

But I encounter errors :

```
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ sudo dpkg -i protonmail-bridge_1.2.7-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package protonmail-bridge.
(Reading database ... 105245 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack protonmail-bridge_1.2.7-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking protonmail-bridge (1.2.7-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of protonmail-bridge:
 protonmail-bridge depends on qt5-default; however:
  Package qt5-default is not installed.
 protonmail-bridge depends on libqt5designer5; however:
  Package libqt5designer5 is not installed.
 protonmail-bridge depends on libqt5multimediawidgets5; however:
  Package libqt5multimediawidgets5 is not installed.
 protonmail-bridge depends on libqt5quickwidgets5; however:
  Package libqt5quickwidgets5 is not installed.
 protonmail-bridge depends on libpulse-mainloop-glib0; however:
  Package libpulse-mainloop-glib0 is not installed.
 protonmail-bridge depends on libsecret-1-0; however:
  Package libsecret-1-0 is not installed.
 protonmail-bridge depends on ttf-dejavu; however:
  Package ttf-dejavu is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package protonmail-bridge (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 protonmail-bridge
```

and :

```
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ sudo apt install protonmail-bridge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
protonmail-bridge is already the newest version (1.2.7-1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 protonmail-bridge : Depends: qt5-default but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqt5designer5 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqt5multimediawidgets5 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqt5quickwidgets5 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libsecret-1-0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ttf-dejavu but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How to install ProtonMail on Ubuntu Server 20.04 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing a package manually, it is expected to have such an error. This is because the dependencies are not installed in your system.

To fix it, you need to do as suggested:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This should install missing dependencies and fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you but it seems a lot of packages https://pastebin.com/sigPb30V

Answer (score 0):

Check if this link helps. It will skip the dependencies step.

I'm able to execute the bridge on Kali after following the below link.

https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/install-bridge-linux-deb-extract-binaries/

Comment: Hi, you should quote the website information, as in case the link die your answer will still be good. Thanks!